# FastApi response and request model

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm pretty new to FastApi, but I was wondering how to set the request model if it's not used in the function. For example, I have:

```
@authenticated.post("/mint/", response_model=MintResponse)
async def create_item(mint: MintRequest):
    return MintResponse(test="test")
```

Here I'm using `mint: MintRequest` to validate the request against the model and using a separate response model to validate outgoing data. But the variable `mint` is unused. If I omit it then the request doesn't get validated, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you're apprently not using `mint` anywhere. When defining `response_model`, generally you don't need to create the response model directly, FastAPI will convert a given dict to that model for you (or a pydantic model, or if the model has `orm_mode` configured, an SQL (or similar) model to the response according to the response model).

Comment: ah i was wondering about the response model as well. how would I go about setting and returning `test="test"` without creating `MintResponse` as I have done?

Comment: you could just return `{"test": "test"}, but _usually_ those values will come from a database or another layer (file, external API, etc.) and not be hardcoded in your function. You can then adjust the response_model depending on how you want the result to be returned (i.e. which fields to be included, even if the dict returned from the service has more fields, etc.)

Comment: Is your linter software complaining about the unused variable? Can't you just add an ignore comment?

Comment: Ok so is it fair to say that I don’t need a response model if I don’t have a database, which I don’t